# Google Blog -- adsense. How to proceed further?

Tags: google-adsense, blog

I started Blogging today and I have used Google Stats and i found that there are 108 visitors(for past 7 hours the time i created by blog). As i'm novice in blogging, this 108 number is good enough to apply for Google adsense? Or I have to wait for some more time so that my page visitors increase,if so why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It makes sense to include Google ads when you think the number of ad clicks will pay you for the work/time investment of including the ads on your pages.

For the first seven hours of your blog's life, <100 visitors is pretty good.  Are you sure these are unique users and are you sure they do not include you visiting your brand new site?  Do you know how these visitors found your site?

When making the decision as to when it's worth the effort to include ads, you will want to know if the number of visitors is sustainable or is just because you told you friends to visit your new site.

My site is new too and I don't want to annoy my users with ads just yet.  When are you willing to do so?

Comment: Yup i know that the users are not my friends, not even i have turned off "Don't track my usage", so these visits are unique ones. So do you mean its better to add ad sense, a little bit later?

Comment: and the number of visitors for yesterday is 305 :D

Comment: Sounds like you are having early success.  Congratulations!

Comment: So i can start Google Adsense now and earn money :) ?

Comment: Certainly you can add Google ads to your site.  The money you make depends on how many of those ads are clicked by your readers.

Comment: no, it may differs from blog to adsense __[visitors blog](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/47599/why-do-blogger-pageview-stats-and-adsense-pageviews-differ)

Answer (score 1):

What you can't easily tell is if those visitors are search engines. However there's no reason why you can't start Adsense now and you may earn money. It may not be very much though unless you get more real visitors who wan't to click on the ads.

Comment: No they aren't search engines for sure..

Comment: Because i get comments for my blog post and i have seen the referencing URLS using Google stats :D