# Why do Blogger pageview stats and AdSense pageviews differ?

Tags: seo, google-adsense, blogger, google-adsense-policies, ppc

I run many blogs for online earnings but my blog in blogger page views:

```
Total Pageviews
90,085
```

And that same blog page views in Google AdSense *Total Pageviews 19,347* are different why? they reduced show for earnings?

My Google AdSense Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!--

google_ad_width=336;
google_ad_height=280;
google_ad_format="336x280_as";
google_ad_type="text_image";
google_ad_host_channel="0001+S0011+L0007";
google_color_border="CCCCCC";
google_color_bg="FFFFFF";
google_color_link="000000";
google_color_url="336699";
google_color_text="000000";
//--></script>
```

Comment: Visitors to your site could be using adblock. Many of the views you see through blogger could be bots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with the other answers - and there are timing differences too.   AdSense "days" are based on the same 24 hours (I think starting and ending at midnight Pacific Time, ie UTC-8).   Blogger stats days may well be based on differnt times - and Analytics days seem to be based on the day/time of the visitor.

All in all, you will never get consistent statistics from the differen tools.   The only realisitic comparisons are within the same tool over time, and perhaps between sites using the same measurements from the same tool (subject to the point about code-lcoation in the template).

Answer (score 3):

Blogger page views count your own visits as well as visit from bots.

You should create a Google Analytics account to get more accurate figures.

Answer (score 2):

The smaller number of views from AdSense is due to it filtering out many that it thinks they are spam.  It also mainly works on a unique IP address, so you may have 1000 page views from only 100 people.  Also people who refresh to quickly are not counted the second time.  Talk to Google about fixing this.

Answer (score 1):

They use different tracking methods. Also it's very important where the code is located. Not every visitor reaches stays on the website until the footer loads, so if you have any tracking code in the footer, that visitor won't get tracked.

AdSense is also JavaScript and if the user has it disabled, then it won't be able to track it.

Answer (score 1):

AdSense identifies unique IP addresses the visitors from different IP addresses will be counted refreshed pages are not counted in AdSense